# Make a filter of a excel data in python

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, python-3.x

I want to make a filter or exception in my code for the excel file.
I have this table in excel

[image]

But in my result I only want the Machine 'S9401-1', how can I Get this.

This is my code

```
import xlrd

 #First open the workbook
wb = xlrd.open_workbook('Book1.xlsx')

 #Then select the sheet. Replace the sheet1 with name of your sheet
sheet = wb.sheet_by_name('connx 94')

 #Then get values of each column. Excuse first item which is header

machine = sheet.cell_value(1,0)
alid = sheet.cell_value(1,1)
descripcion = sheet.cell_value(1,3)
result=[machine,alid,descripcion]
print (result)
```

Comment: xlrd package can't apply a filter, it's designed to *read* Excel files and has very limited functionality in that regard. I am certain you can do this with `win32com` which exposes the full Excel object model (or nearly so) to apply a filter, **or** you could return the full dataset to a list object in python and remove the elements that don't match your criteria.

Comment: You could simply add a condtion to check for  'S9401-1' in your python code. Or you could consider using openpyxl (https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/filters.html)

Comment: Have you had a chance to try my suggested answer, below? This seems to work when I have tested it.

Comment: @DavidZemens Your answer is correct  and I can use for another things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using only `xlrd` package, you could do brute force like this:

```
import xlrd
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(r'c:\debug\py.xlsx')
sheet = wb.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
def filterdata(sh,ID):
    vals = sh.row_values
    data = [[vals(r,0)[1], vals(r,0)[3]] for r in range(sh.nrows) if vals(r,0)[0] == ID]
    return data

print(filterdata(sheet,'S9401-1))
```

Making a function call, you can use different IDs:

```
print(filterdata(sheet,'S9401-1'))
print(filterdata(sheet,'S9401-3'))  # should return an empty list
```